# Two flairs for Qiaochu Yuan

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderators, election

Heads up: on the [$2010$ moderator election page](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/1) and the [main elections page](https://math.stackexchange.com/election), there are two flairs for Qiaochu Yuan present.[image]

Am I the only seeing this or is it intentional?

Comment: I see it too. Of course, he is pretty awesome...

Comment: Also, on the main elections page, his flair is the only "clickable" one for 2010.

Comment: In reality Qiaochu is a cover for a Bourbaki-like group of grad students. Ever wondered how he got so many points both here and on MathOverflow, and how he knows so much about so many topics? So it turns out that two of the Qiaochu members are moderators, so the flair appears twice. But now that you know the truth...

Comment: A new proof of Banach-Tarski by Q.

Comment: Chuck Norris would have three flairs, of course.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Chuck Norris would have $\omega$ flairs.

Comment: And Steven Segal? $\omega+1$?

Answer (score 5):

The markup for the retults is um... person generated.

Corrected now :)

Comment: Corrected manually, or is it code generated now?